# Create custom keypad for regional language?

Tags: android, android-keypad

In my application I have made a malayalam (a regional language)keypad by creating a custom Xml file.An it shows malayalam word.But when I click I am not able to parse keypad values.It is showing an error in log cat.Is there any method to implement regional languages in android application.I have also used a ttf file in assets/fonts.Does any one have new ideas please share with me.

Comment: please post your log cat

Comment: 02-11 10:08:19.505: E/Keyboard(387): Error parsing keycodes

Comment: SREEJITH here is the link [here](http://code.google.com/p/softkeyboard/source/browse/trunk/project/src/com/menny/android/anysoftkeyboard/keyboards/AnyKeyboard.java?r=1643) if still you are facing prob them i will post my softkeyboard code

Comment: Ok sir .Let me try this

Comment: @YogeshTatwal How can I implement malayalam keypad with the above link.Can u post the softkeyboard code